# MySQL compare then delete the shorter string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
company_name  |  description   
-----------------------------
google        |  a great search engine!
facebook      |  connect with friends!
```

I'm adding more companies to the list, with the potential of duplicate companies - if a duplicate is added I want the one with a longer description. So if I added:

```
google    |  empty
facebook  | facebook is an enterprise software for connecting individuals around the world
```

I want the final table to look like:

```
company_name  |  description   
-----------------------------
google        |  a great search engine!
facebook      |  facebook is an enterprise software for connecting individuals around the world
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL or do I need to look into more robust services, like Google BigQuery or something?

Comment: With a stored procedure it is doable in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

```
INSERT INTO companies (company_name, description) VALUES ('facebook', 'some new description')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    description = IF(LENGTH(VALUES(description)) > LENGTH(description), VALUES(description), description)
```

`VALUES(description)` is the new value being inserted, `description` is the old value. This compares their lengths and assigns the longer one.

I'm assuming `company_name` is a unique key in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just insert all the rows in the table and then fetch the one with the longest description:

```
select company_name, description
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company_name order by length(description) desc) as seqnum
      from companies c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```